# can we create instance variable in the same class default constructor of that class type?

Tags: java, netbeans

In the Following class HiddenWord, I am creating a instance variable which is initialised through a string. Is it correct way of doing?

Also, when I use this object, do I require a toString method to do so?

```
public class HiddenWord{

private String Hword;

public HiddenWord(String word){


   Hword = new HiddenWord(word);
}

}
```

Comment: If you call `new HiddenWord(...)` inside the constructor `HiddenWord` it won't work. You should always try compiling the code before you post it here; the error messages, if you get any, will instruct you. And `Hword` should be spelled `hiddenWord` or `hWord` to conform to the naming conventions for Java. Spelling it like a type will confuse people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we create instance variable in the same class default constructor of that class type?

It is possible but your types are not same in your code. You have String type variable and your Class type is `HiddenWord`.

And when you do

```
 Hword = new HiddenWord(word); // wrong.
```

No That is wrong. Because A string is not a `HiddenWord`.

you just need to assign the received String to the varaible `Hword`

```
 this.Hword =word;
```

> Also, when I use this object, do I require a toString method to do so?

That really depends on how you are using it. Just to show the contents of this class ? Yes.

BTW, varaible names starts with lowercase in java.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: yes, you have to explicitly call the toString method to store your newly created HiddenWorld object as a String in Hword.

Second, this is a **very bad idea**. Calling the constructor there will cause recursion and a StackOverflowError, because every time you call the constructor it will call itself again, and keep on filling up the stack with new method calls.

Third, in the assumption that you want to store the given word in Hword, simply do this:

```
Hword = word;
```

Extra:
The toString method is always present for any objects you create, since it's defined in the Object class, which is extended by all other classes.